# Why does the JPA findBy method return an empty result?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

When trying to find a member using the webId field in the Member class, even if the input is correct, it is unable to find the member.
Postman
I would like to know the cause.

Service:

```
@Slf4j
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class OAuthService {

    private final MemberRepository memberRepository;

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public LoginWebResDto webLogin(LoginWebReqDto req) throws BaseException {
        Member member = memberRepository.findByWebId(req.getId()).orElseThrow(() -> new BaseException(ErrorCode.LOGIN_ERROR));

        if (!passwordEncoder.matches(req.getPassword(), member.getWebPassword())) {
            System.out.println(member.getWebPassword());
            throw new BaseException(ErrorCode.LOGIN_ERROR);
        }

        return new LoginWebResDto(member.getWebId());
    }
    ...
}
```

Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface MemberRepository extends JpaRepository<Member, Long> {
    Optional<Member> findByEmail(String email);
    Optional<Member> findByWebId(String webId);
    boolean existsByWebId(String webId);
    Member findByWebToken(String webToken);
}
```

Member:

```
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
@Entity
@Table(name = "member")
public class Member extends BaseTimeEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "member_id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "web_id")
    private String webId;

    @Column(name = "web_password")
    private String webPassword;
}
```

Comment: Well despite you think the input is correct it isn't. Check for casing, is it a `varchar` or `char` column. What do you get which expection.

Comment: Could you show us your db columns, maybe you've got wrong naming or data type.

Comment: You can try to log the query generated by hibernate. This might make it easier to debug. More info on how to do it here : https://thorben-janssen.com/hibernate-tips-how-to-log-sql-statements-and-their-parameters/ or here https://mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-display-hibernate-sql-parameter-values-log4j/

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The way you've defined your Member class, there is no way for java to set the field values of your the class even if the query returns some data. You have only defined the getters and a NoArgsConstructor, there is no AllArgsConstructor present, or setters for the individual fields.

Try adding `@Data` annotation, or other equivalent annotations (`@AllArgsConstructor`, `@Setter`) for java to be able to set these fields in case some data is returned by the query. The code in repository class looks fine to me.